# Странное поведение списков в Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть два внешне одинаковых списка, один задан напрямую, второй сформирован с помощью `.append`. Почему они ведут себя по-разному? Этот код:

```py
s1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
s2 = []
l = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(4):
    s2.append(l)
s1[2][2] = 5
s2[2][2] = 5 # добавляет 5 в каждый список
print s1, '\n', s2
```

возвращает:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 5, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. вы в `s2.append(l)` добавляете не значение, а ссылку на объект, то и получается, что у вас массив состоит из одинаковых объектов, изменяя один - изменяются и все остальные, включая изначальный `l`.

Самый простой вариант решения - изменить строчку на `s2.append(list(l))`, тогда уже будет передаваться не ссылка на объект, а его значение.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором случае не четыре списка, а один и тот же список, но четыре раза.